# Wrong type of reflected struct

Tags: reflection, go

I have 2 different packages(pkg1, pkg2), in first i have code that calls function from another package

file#1

```
package pkg1
import "pkg2"
import "reflect"

type User struct {
  name string
  ...
}

func main() {
  fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf((*User)(nil)) //=> *User
  pkg2.RegisterStruct(reflect.TypeOf((*User)(nil))
  //pkg2.RegisterStruct(reflect.TypeOf(&User{}) // also tried this way
}
```

file#2

```
package pkg2

import "reflect"

func RegisterStruct(u interface{}) { // also tried to have argument type as reflect.Type
 fmt.Println(u) //=> *reflect.rtype
}
```

Why type was `reflect.rtype` instead of `*User` ?
And how do i correctly pass type to another pkg?

Comment: The code given here is incapable of producing the output you say it does.

Comment: Please read about creating an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (minimal, complete, and verifiable example). Your code snippets are not valid. When edited to make them compile (mostly missing parenthesis) both `Println` statements give me "*pkg1.User" with Go1.4.2. (Note, `fmt.Printf("%T %#v\n", u, u)` does give `*reflect.rtype &reflect.rtype{…`; but that's not what you claim to have used).

Comment: And, either expect and deal with a `reflect.Type` or don't pass that it (i.e. just do `pkg2.Register((*User)(nil))` if you don't want/expect an `reflect.Type`).

Answer (score -2):

The `reflect.TypeOf()` returns a `reflect.Type` now you are doing two completely different things with: In the first call to Println (the "correct" one) this `reflect.Type` is wrapped inside an `interface{}` (during the call to Println) while in the second (the "wrong" one) you wrap the `reflect.Type` inside an `interface{}` while calling RegisterSturct and you then rewrap it once more inside an additional `interface{}` while calling Println. Println just removes one layer of interface{}-wrapping.

## Sorry, this is nonsense. I'll have to think a bit more. Would delete if possible.

Comment: reflect.Type is an interface type already. There is no "wrapping inside an `interface{}`" that happens during the call `RegisterStruct` or `fmt.Println`, and certainly no double wrapping.

Comment: Sorry, that was too quick. The second is just a copy of an interface value, it is not repacked. Will delete.